# What is v4 rendering mode in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am working with a webControl which has a property named `EnableV4Rendering`. However, I have no idea what it is and what it does. The problem is this property will disable my webControl if I set it to true and break the css when it is false.

So could anyone tell me what is v4 rendering mode and how it affect the control?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spcalendarview.enablev4rendering.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

^The webControl ^

Answer (score 1):

UI Version `4` refers to `SharePoint 2010`. Regrading calendar view, it could be rendered in two modes:

- *classic* mode available for SharePoint 2007 version and previous (for backward compatibility)
- *ajax* mode available for SharePoint 2010 or above (default)

Once the version of `SharePoint is 2010` or above and [`SPCalendarView.EnableV4Rendering` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spcalendarview.enablev4rendering.aspx) is set to `true`, calendar view is getting rendered using *ajax calendar view*